# Can you insert middleware in an Node.JS Express app

Tags: node.js, express

Is there a way to inject middleware in an Express stack? What I mean is I want to have my app.js setup the main middleware chain, and then call other modules passing the app instance and they may want to insert more middleware (e.g. an authentication module that wants to add passport in at the correct place)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can certainly pass your `app` object to other modules and call `use` there.  Of course, middleware functions are executed **in the order they are added**, so you have to take great care to ensure that you call `use` in the correct order.

app.js

```
var app = express();
// ...

app.use(express.logger()); // first middleware function

var someOtherModule = require('./mod.js');
someOtherModule.init(app);

app.use(express.static()); // last middleware function)
```

mod.js

```
exports.init = function(app) {
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {

    });
};
```

---

As far as actually *injecting* a middleware function in the middle of the stack (after you've already called `app.use` with a set of middleware functions), there's no documented way to do it.  `use` only adds a function to the end of the stack.

`use` is actually supplied by Connect in [proto.js](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/2.7.0/lib/proto.js#L62-93):

```
app.use = function(route, fn){

  ...

  this.stack.push({ route: route, handle: fn });

  return this;
};
```

*Technically*, you could fiddle with `app.stack` yourself, but **I would not do this**.  You'd be messing with an undocumented implementation detail, which is liable to change.  In other words, it's possible a future update to *either* Connect or Express could break your app.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't think there was a way (can't think of an easy way to say where it would be put).  I'm probably going to go with the way you suggest up front.

Comment: huge win for indicating that order is important! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use app.use(fn) or stack them like this:

```
app.get('/foo', fn1, fn2, fn3);
```

The signature has to always be the same and call next();

```
function(req, res, next) {
  next();
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I don't understand what is the problem?

You can add any function in middleware:

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
   //some munipulation with req and res
   next()
})
```

And you can send this `app` into you're moduls

Comment: I think the problem is that `app.use` always adds your middleware function *to the end* of the stack, so middleware added earlier may complete the request before you function gets a chance to run.

Comment: For example? When is it need?

Comment: To try and keep things more modular - so I want everything to do with authentication in authenticate.js - it creates the passport object inside there so rather than pass it out I'd rather pass app in and ket that module add the passport.initialize and passport.session middleware just after the express.session but before router

Comment: But you can create a module authentification and make somethings like module.exports = exports = function(app){
 ///here add all with passport 
}